# La barra de desplazamiento del reproductor de audio no funciona

Tags: javascript

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Parece que la barra que controla el tiempo del audio no funciona.

Dentro del script (inicializo la variable `seeking=false`):

```js
seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");

seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  seeking = true;
  seek(event);
});
seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  seek(event);
});
seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  seeking = false;
});

function seek(event) {
  if (seeking) {
    seekslider.value = event.clientX - seekslider.offsetLeft;
    var seekto = audio.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
    audio.currentTime = seekto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. ¿Estás usando algún tutorial para crear esta funcionalidad?, por favor [edit] tu pregunta y proporciona un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: declarando la variable seeking funciona bien, puedes especifiacar bien cual es el error que te da?

Comment: @DanielPérez Parece que ese es el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La barra funciona bien, solo tenias que definir la variable `seeking` global, y para que el ejemplo funcionara definir el objeto audio

```js
seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
var audio = {
  duration: 30
};
var seeking = false;
seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  seeking = true;
  seek(event);
});
seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  seek(event);
});
seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  seeking = false;
});

function seek(event) {
  if (seeking) {
    seekslider.value = event.clientX - seekslider.offsetLeft;
    var seekto = audio.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
    audio.currentTime = seekto;
    console.log(audio);
  }
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" />
</div>
```